# Following EAV in my Modules

Tags: eav

Is it necessary to follow EAV with the models I create for my modules?  If not always, when should I and when shouldn't I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No it is not necessary**, especially if you're using your own tables and your own schema for data storage; and that schema is fixed (not end-user-defined).

EAV was used as the basis of Customer, Products (and, once upon a time, Sales) because the schema (business needs) for every install of Magento is potentially  different - e.g. some may want to gather a customer's Pet Name during registration, while others would want a product attribute called Flavor.

In short, define your application's scope and the data storage schema - then use Magento's built-in Resource models (ORM) to provide access and CRUD capabilities.

Comment: Don't forget customer address and categories! :-)

Comment: And Credit Memo, Invoice and Shipment... and (EE) RMA Item...

Comment: Credit and invoice were flattened along with other sales entities...?

Comment: LOL I thought we were compiling the full list of once upon a time. Le sigh.